# Most lightweight way to host a html/css/js UI?

Tags: c++, html, css

I'm writing a pure Win32 application in MSVC 2012 using C++. After lots of struggling with trying to theme native win32 (I don't want to use .NET) I wouldn't mind seeing if I can do it much easier by having the application frontend rendered from HTML/CSS (which is easy to theme).

What lightweight libraries are there available for C++ that would let me have a web styled frontend on my desktop application, while seamlessly giving the user the impression that they aren't looking at a webpage?

Comment: This is a tall order, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/ could help you out.